# Uncaught TypeError: $(...).modal is not a function, can't manage proper order

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

Possibly I did wrong script order,I am trying make a dynamic pop up modal, which will fetch data on click. my scripts are :

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/summernote@0.8.18/dist/summernote.min.css" 
    rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" 
    href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" 
    href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384- 
   Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- Font Awesome Intigration -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font- 
    awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" 
     href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.carousel.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" 
 href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{asset('css/style.css')}}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('css/responsive.css')}}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('css/fundraisers.css')}}">
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('css/support.css')}}"> -->
     @yield('head-script')
    
    <!-- must include  -->
    
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

    {{-- for sweetalert2   --}}
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@10"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/2.1.2/sweetalert.min.js" 
     integrity="sha512- 
     AA1Bzp5Q0K1KanKKmvN/4d3IRKVlv9PYgwFPvm32nPO6QS8yH1HO7LbgB1pgiOxPtfeg5zEn2ba64MUcqJx6CA==" 
     crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
     <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/webcamjs/1.0.25/webcam.min.js"></script>
     <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" 
     integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" 
     crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="{{asset('js/languageChange.js')}}"></script>
     <script src="{{ asset('js/share.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('js/main.js') }}"></script>
    <title>Mortfund</title>

    <!-- Fonts -->
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" />
     
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css"
      integrity="sha512- 
   iBBXm8fW90+nuLcSKlbmrPcLa0OT92xO1BIsZ+ywDWZCvqsWgccV3gFoRBv0z+8dLJgyAHIhR35VZc2oM/gI1w=="
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nunito:wght@400;600;700&display=swap" 
  rel="stylesheet">
```

Laravel Body tag goes here ------

```
    <script src="{{ url('js/authentication.js') }}"></script>
    
    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" 
  integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" 
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- Option 1: jQuery and Bootstrap Bundle (includes Popper) -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"> 
    </script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/owl.carousel.min.js"> 
    </script>
    <script src="{{asset('js/script.js')}}"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/waypoints/4.0.1/jquery.waypoints.min.js"> 
    </script>

    <script src="{{asset('js/jquery.countup.js')}}"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/summernote@0.8.18/dist/summernote.min.js"></script>
   <script>
```

I excluded html and body tags to reduce the amount of code, which is not good for a posting in stack overflow. If you have any question please ask me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you loaded JQuery thrice :

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

You need to load JQuery once in a page, If you loaded JQuery more than once then you will face error, [Why do I need to load jquery twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38490197/why-do-i-need-to-load-jquery-twice)

Comment: I removed one, still getting the error

Comment: Its not twice actually, I got thrice. Load your page and get the source code with `CTRL + U` and search for `Jquery` and see how many times jquery loaded on your page

Comment: Thanks, I actually added 4 js lol .Now it's working